swiftui How can I get the NavigationLink to fire once if there are 2 navigation links in a cell
I am recently learning the new navigation workflow and am encountering an issue . I have a cell that sometimes contains a fullname and a place/location name . If I click on the fullname then I want to go to the dataNameView and if I click on place then I want to go to DataPlaceView . The issue is that if a cell contains both fullname and place name then it fires twice and goes into both case statements
    .navigationDestination(for: SampleDestination.self) { destination in
        switch destination {
        case .dataNameView(let data):
            DataNameView(data: data)
        case .dataPlaceView(let data):
            DataPlaceView(data: data)
        }
    }

For cells that only have FullName then it works correctly and goes to dataNameView . How can I get this to work correctly as I am still learning . This is the code
    struct APIData: Identifiable, Hashable {
        let id = UUID()
        var fullname: String
        var profileid: Int
        var placeid: Int
        var placename: String {
            placeid == 0 ? "" : _placename
        }
        
        private var _placename: String
        
        init(fullname: String, profileid: Int, placeid: Int, placename: String) {
            self.fullname = fullname
            self.profileid = profileid
            self.placeid = placeid
            self._placename = placename
        }
    }
    
    let sampleData: [APIData] = [
        APIData(fullname: "John Doe", profileid: 1, placeid: 0, placename: ""),
        APIData(fullname: "Jane Smith", profileid: 2, placeid: 1, placename: "New York"),
        APIData(fullname: "Mike Johnson", profileid: 3, placeid: 2, placename: "Los Angeles"),
        APIData(fullname: "Emily Davis", profileid: 4, placeid: 0, placename: ""),
        APIData(fullname: "Chris Wilson", profileid: 5, placeid: 3, placename: "Chicago"),
        APIData(fullname: "Sara Brown", profileid: 6, placeid: 0, placename: ""),
        APIData(fullname: "David Clark", profileid: 7, placeid: 4, placename: "Houston"),
        APIData(fullname: "Amy Moore", profileid: 8, placeid: 5, placename: "Phoenix"),
        APIData(fullname: "Robert Taylor", profileid: 9, placeid: 0, placename: ""),
        APIData(fullname: "Laura Anderson", profileid: 10, placeid: 6, placename: "Philadelphia"),
        APIData(fullname: "Mark Lee", profileid: 11, placeid: 7, placename: "San Antonio"),
        APIData(fullname: "Patricia Martinez", profileid: 12, placeid: 0, placename: ""),
        APIData(fullname: "James White", profileid: 13, placeid: 8, placename: "San Diego"),
        APIData(fullname: "Jennifer Lewis", profileid: 14, placeid: 9, placename: "Dallas"),
        APIData(fullname: "Daniel Harris", profileid: 15, placeid: 0, placename: ""),
        APIData(fullname: "Jessica Walker", profileid: 16, placeid: 10, placename: "San Jose"),
        APIData(fullname: "Michael Hall", profileid: 17, placeid: 11, placename: "Austin"),
        APIData(fullname: "Emma Allen", profileid: 18, placeid: 0, placename: ""),
        APIData(fullname: "Christopher Young", profileid: 19, placeid: 12, placename: "Jacksonville"),
        APIData(fullname: "Olivia King", profileid: 20, placeid: 13, placename: "Fort Worth")
    ]
    
    enum SampleDestination: Hashable {
        case dataNameView(APIData)
        case dataPlaceView(APIData)
    }
    
    struct DataNameView: View {
        var data: APIData
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text("Full Name: \(data.fullname)")
                    .font(.headline)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Name Detail")
        }
    }
    
    struct DataPlaceView: View {
        var data: APIData
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text("Place Name: \(data.placename)")
                    .font(.headline)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Place Detail")
        }
    }
    
    struct SampleDataView: View {
        var body: some View {
            NavigationStack {
                List(sampleData) { data in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        NavigationLink(value: SampleDestination.dataNameView(data)) {
                            Text(data.fullname)
                                .font(.headline)
                        }
                        if data.placeid != 0 {
                            NavigationLink(value: SampleDestination.dataPlaceView(data)) {
                                Text(data.placename)
                                    .font(.subheadline)
                                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.vertical, 4)
                }
                .navigationTitle("Sample Data")
                .navigationDestination(for: SampleDestination.self) { destination in
                    switch destination {
                    case .dataNameView(let data):
                        DataNameView(data: data)
                    case .dataPlaceView(let data):
                        DataPlaceView(data: data)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

struct SampleDataView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SampleDataView()
    }
}


you need 2 navigationDestination, one for place and one for name.
